# What is the name of the background music in Atari 2600 Parachute

Tags: game-music-identification, parachute

This game had a guy in a parachute falling down and the objective was to help him avoid all the hazards such as planes and birds

It had the same music looping in the background, with the scale of the music changing after every loop

This is the game I am talking about:

Surprisingly I can't find the name of the tune with a google search about the game, but I think I've heard it in other places so I'm sure it's a popular one

What is the name of the background tune?

Comment: "but I think I have heard it in other places" chances are, it likely was made for the game, and since you can't actually confirm where you heard it, it could just be confirmation bias of a sort. I would be shocked if it was an actual named piece of music, all things considered.

Comment: Most game music can be found by searching "<Game Name> OST". If the track doesn't have an official name it's likely just named after the level or activity that you're doing like "Level 2-8", "Title Theme", "Credits Theme" etc.

Answer (score 2):

The tracks don't appear to have official names other than 'Background Music'. [VGMusic.com](https://www.vgmusic.com/music/console/atari/2600/) simply calls them:

- BGM 1
- BGM 2
- BGM 3

With each representing the different 'scales' that you hear in each screen. You can download them as MIDI files from the same source.

Comment: As for sounding familiar, I can't say I've ever heard that *specific* tune, it is however reminiscent of air levels from a few games although nothing I can pin down definitively. Perhaps they all draw from a similar source?

Comment: Thanks but I think I've found the original song. Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

The tune is a cover of the first part of the song [The Longest Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa1yUAal0K4) by Paul Anka, from the [movie of the same name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056197/)

Information about this game seems to be hard to find so I haven't found any official statement that the game's background music is indeed a cover of this song, but the tunes are so similar that it's apparent they are the same

Here's an instrumental version